# Is there a smooth proper family whose fibers are not Mazur-Ogus?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory

Set $K$ to be a number field, denote by $\mathcal{O}_K$ the integer ring of $K$. My question is the following:

Is there a smooth proper family $X \to \mathcal{O}_K$ whose fibers are not Mazur-Ogus?

Comment: What is Mazur-Ogus?

Comment: Thank you Stan. We call a proper smooth variety over a positive characteristic Mazur-Ogus if the crystalline cohomology groups are torsion free, and Hodge to de Rham spectrum sequence degenerate at E_1. Joshi defined it here https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6402.

Comment: This will hold for all primes except for finitely many.

Comment: What's mean of "fiber"? If it means the special fibre, as Piotr Achinger pointed out, this will hold for all primes except for finitely many because of Deligne-Illusie argument. Then we can ask which variety has Mazur-Ogus fibre for all primes, and I'm not sure with that question because Deligne-Illusie aurgument works only in $\dim X<p$ case.

Comment: So if "whose fibers" means "all of whose fibers", then the answer is no: $H^*_{\rm dR}(X/\mathcal{O}_K[1/N])$ as well as the relative Hodge groups will be locally free with formation commuting with base change for some $N$, and then you get torsion-free crystalline cohomology for primes not dividing $N$ by Berthelot's comparison, and degenerate spectral sequence because it degenerates in char. 0 (or indeed by Deligne-Illusie in char. bigger than dimension). If you mean "some fibers", then constructing interesting smooth proper $X/\mathcal{O}_K$ is hard (often impossible for $K=\mathbf{Q}$)...

Comment: (continued) ... But I guess that it is known that there exist Enriques surfaces over $\mathcal{O}_K$ (not for $K=\mathbf{Q}$ by work of Schroer). That would likely give you something which is not Mazur-Ogus at a prime above $2$.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger There are indeed number fields $K$ such that there exist Enriques surfaces over $O_K$; this follows from work of Moret-Bailly on Skolem's problem (applied to the moduli of Enriques surfaces).